# How to export my mac terminal theme?

Tags: bash, macos, command-line

I've customized my terminal theme but I'd like to be able to share it with people. I know I've been able to download ".terminal" files, in the past. Where are these files located on a Mac?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to export a Terminal theme (profile settings) from `Terminal->Help->Terminal Help`, search for "exporting".

To export a theme (profile settings file):

> Export profile settings
>
> - Choose Terminal->Preferences, then click Profiles
> - Drag a profile from the Profiles list to the Finder
>
> Terminal creates a settings file in the Finder that can be used on
>   another computer.

To import a profile setting:

> Import a settings file
>
> If you want to use the settings from another computer, you can import
>   a Terminal settings file from that other computer.
>
> The file name of the Terminal settings file usually ends with a
>   “.terminal” extension.
>
> Before you can import the settings file, it must be exported from the other system and placed in a location where you can access it.
>
> - Choose Terminal > Preferences, then click Profiles.
> - In the Finder, locate the settings file, then drag it to the Profiles list.

Comment: Whats wrong with Shell→Export Settings? This also keeps the theme, I use this all the time.

Comment: @Maximus Nothing is wrong with Shell->Export Settings. It exports the profile of the current session. However, the Help instructions are available and they show how to export *any* profile and how to import them as well, so I decided to answer the question that way.